# Выход(завершение) из родительской процедуры в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть две хранимых процедуры:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ACCESS_CHECK( IN iPROC_NAME TEXT )
BEGIN
    IF (RIGHT(iPROC_NAME, 3) IN ('ADD', 'CNG', 'DEL', 'ITM'))       
    THEN
        SET @LEAVE_QUERY = CONCAT('LEAVE ', iPROC_NAME);
        PREPARE LEAVE_QUERY FROM @LEAVE_QUERY;
        EXECUTE LEAVE_QUERY;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE LEAVE_QUERY;
    END IF;
END;
```

И

```
CREATE PROCEDURE INFO_ITM( IN iPROC_NAME TEXT )
INFO_ITM:BEGIN
    CALL ACCESS_CHECK('INFO_ITM');
    -- bla bla bla
END;
```

При попытку выйти из процедуры, mysql кидает syntax error. Есть ли другой способ завершить родительскую процедуру?

Comment: `leave` производит выход из блока с меткой. во первых у вас меток для перехода нет. Во вторых `execute` выполняет SQL запрос, а не инструкцию языка процедур (к которым относится `leave`). т.е. в любом случае вы не сможете так сделать. единственный выход (если у вас все таки есть метки) делать явные `if iPROC_NAME like 'ADD%' then leave ADD` и т.п.

Comment: @Mike я просто процедуры как пример писал, забыл метки. Хардкод в моем случае наверно хороший вариант.

Comment: Трансформируйте ACCESS_CHECK в функцию, возвращающую True, если надо завершить, и False в противном случае. И используйте это значения для завершения/выхода.

Answer (score 0):

Возвращайте из вложенной процедуры признак, что нужно завершить внешнюю

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ACCESS_CHECK( IN iPROC_NAME TEXT, OUT IS_EXIT BOOLEAN)
BEGIN
    IF (RIGHT(iPROC_NAME, 3) IN ('ADD', 'CNG', 'DEL', 'ITM'))       
    THEN
      SET IS_EXIT = TRUE;
    ELSE
      SET IS_EXIT = NULL;
    END IF;
END;

CREATE PROCEDURE INFO_ITM( IN iPROC_NAME TEXT )
INFO_ITM:BEGIN
  DECLARE var_exit BOOLEAN
  CALL ACCESS_CHECK('INFO_ITM', var_exit);
  IF (var_exit IS NOT NULL)
    LEAVE INFO_ITM;
  END IF;
END;
```